# Caching of combined CSS and JS fails because of losing MIME types through combining by PHP

Tags: plugins, php, css, javascript, cache

On using any combining plugin for CSS and JS files they "lose" their correct MIME type - because combining plugins do their job by PHP.

So the result of this job, file alike http://www.example.com/assets/style.css?combined=20180202 aren't recognized as CSS, but as PHP, and my cache settings for CSS files don't work for them.

Same game with JS: files like http://www.example.com/assets/script.js?combined=20180202 aren't recognized as JS, but as PHP and cache settings for JS don'r work for such combined files.

What can i do to correctly cache combined files?

Comment: Do you send the MIME type header? Did you think about leaving the query parameter and maybe use it in the filename (I think files with query param aren't cached by default?)

Comment: All the plugins I've used combine the CSS & JS into actual files in the filesystem. These will almost certainly have the correct type. Virtual files that don't actually exist, but are dynamically created in PHP _on request_ might not, but only if the developer neglected to send the correct headers. Dynamically generating the combined file on every request though probably wouldn't help performance, and might even hurt it, so it would not be the best method to do this.